# Что нужно исправить? чтобы часть после else работала

Tags: python, python-3.6

Что нужно исправить? чтобы часть после else работала так же как часть до нее, т.е. задается вопрос при ответе на него выдается ответ. И как после этого зациклить код, чтобы при ответе "Nein" программа стартовала заново, а при ответе "Ja" выдавало сообщение message_J.
Cпасибо!

```
question = input('Wie heißt du?')
answer = input('Bist du Frau oder Mann?')

message_N = "GO AGAIN BOYS!!!"
message_E = "Nein"
message_J = "Too bad, lmao"
message_f = f"Sehr geehrte Frau {question},\nIch grüße dich!"
message_m = f"Sehr geehrter Herr {question}, \nIch grüße dich!"


if question == str():
    print(answer)
if answer == "Mann":
    print(message_m)
elif answer == "Frau":
    print(message_f)
**else:
    answer == input('Bist du jemanden anderer?')
    print(answer)
if answer == "Ja":
    print(message_J)
elif answer == "Nein":
    print(message_N)**
```

Comment: "чтобы при ответе "Nein" программа стартовала заново" тебе нужен while тогда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень просто. Создайте цикл `while True`. Вот код:

```
message_N = "GO AGAIN BOYS!!!"
message_E = "Nein"
message_J = "Too bad, lmao"

while True: #Создаем бесконечный цикл
    question = input('Wie heißt du?')
    answer = input('Bist du Frau oder Mann?')

    message_f = f"Sehr geehrte Frau {question},\nIch grüße dich!"
    message_m = f"Sehr geehrter Herr {question}, \nIch grüße dich!"

    if question == str():
        print(answer)
    if answer == "Mann":
        print(message_m)
    elif answer == "Frau":
        print(message_f)
    else:
        answer == input('Bist du jemanden anderer?')
        print(answer)
    if answer == "Ja":
        print(message_J)
        break #Выходим из цикла
    elif answer == "Nein":
        print(message_N)
        continue #Запускаем цикл заново
```

[Подробнее](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/cikl-while-v-python) про цикл `while`.

Comment: удалил часть с print

 else:
        answer == input('Bist du jemanden anderer?')

    if answer == "Ja":
        print(message_J)
        break #Выходим из цикла
    elif answer == "Nein":
        print(message_N)
        continue #Запускаем цикл заново
но output циклиться на этом вопросе, т.е. задает его бесконечно в не зависимости от того, что я ответил и никаких сообщений не выводит.

Comment: У вас ошибка в строчке "answer == input('Bist du jemanden anderer?')". Здесь вы не присваиваете значение переменной "answer", а сравниваете. В место "==" поставте "=".

Comment: Спасибо! единственное, хотел чтобы, цикл запускал весь код с самого начала, а получается при ответе Nein, целиться только код после else:

Answer (score 0):

вот так что ли надо?

```
question = input('Wie heißt du?')
answer = input('Bist du Frau oder Mann?')

message_N = "GO AGAIN BOYS!!!"
message_E = "Nein"
message_J = "Too bad, lmao"
message_f = f"Sehr geehrte Frau {question},\nIch grüße dich!"
message_m = f"Sehr geehrter Herr {question}, \nIch grüße dich!"


if question == str():
    print(answer)
    if answer == "Mann":
        print(message_m)
    elif answer == "Frau":
        print(message_f)
else:
    answer == input('Bist du jemanden anderer?')
    print(answer)
    if answer == "Ja":
        print(message_J)
    elif answer == "Nein":
        print(message_N)
```

Comment: а к чему вообще проверка `if question == str():`? разве там может быть вообще не строка?)

Comment: кто его знает - автор же не описал логику программы

Answer (score 0):

```
message_N = "GO AGAIN BOYS!!!"
message_E = "Nein"
message_J = "Too bad, lmao"


while True:
    question = input('Wie heißt du?')
    answer = input('Bist du Frau oder Mann?')
    message_f = f"Sehr geehrte Frau {question},\nIch grüße dich!"
    message_m = f"Sehr geehrter Herr {question}, \nIch grüße dich!"
    if question == str():
        print(answer)
    if answer == "Mann":
        print(message_m)
        break
    elif answer == "Frau":
        print(message_f)
        break
    else:
        answer = input('Bist du jemanden anderer?')

    if answer == "Ja":
        print(message_J)
        break
    elif answer == "Nein":
        print(message_N)
        continue
```

Comment: это я так, дописал, до того что хотел в самом конце, спасибо @Никита!

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]